multiple options with LIKE REPLACE
select *
from V
where NVL(V.COD,'*') LIKE  REPLACE  ( '?CODE - (*R01* , R0* , * FOR ALL)?' ,'*', '%' )

With the script, users can specify the data in the way below.
 *R01*   --- for R01;
 R0*     --- for R01 to R09;
 *     --- for all;

Is there a way to let users select multiple options to specify something like
R01,R02 or R12,R03,R33


Just throw on your additional conditions with ORs. For every value, you have a separate LIKE test, each test separated by OR. That's all an IN operator is under the covers anyway. You may want to index (NVL(COD,'*')) as a function-based index to have any hope of not doing a full table scan, and even then you'd need to avoid any leading %.

This is SQL*Plus example so I used substitution variable. As it appears twice in code, I have to undefine it before running query again. You, probably, don't use that tool so it might be a bind variable (i.e. :par_cod) or whatever ?CODE represents (I don't recognize that).
Query uses regular expressions to split comma-separated list of cod values into rows so that they are used in IN, along with code you already have.
Sample data:
SQL> with test (cod, name) as
  2    (select 'R01', 'Harry Potter' from dual union all
  3     select 'R02', 'Ron Weasley'  from dual union all
  4     select 'R03', 'Superman'     from dual union all
  5     select 'R04', 'Batman'       from dual union all
  6     select 'R05', 'Gladiator'    from dual union all
  7     select 'R06', 'Furiosa'      from dual
  8    )

Query begins here:
  9  select *
 10  from test
 11  where cod in (select regexp_substr('&&par_cod', '[^,]+', 1, level)
 12                from dual
 13                connect by level <= regexp_count('&&par_cod', ',') + 1
 14               )
 15     or cod like replace('&&par_cod', '*', '%');
Enter value for par_cod: R01

COD NAME
--- ------------
R01 Harry Potter

SQL> undefine par_cod
SQL> /
Enter value for par_cod: R0*

COD NAME
--- ------------
R01 Harry Potter
R02 Ron Weasley
R03 Superman
R04 Batman
R05 Gladiator
R06 Furiosa

6 rows selected.

Some more testing:
SQL> undefine par_cod
SQL> /
Enter value for par_cod: *

COD NAME
--- ------------
R01 Harry Potter
R02 Ron Weasley
R03 Superman
R04 Batman
R05 Gladiator
R06 Furiosa

6 rows selected.

SQL> undefine par_cod
SQL> /
Enter value for par_cod: R01,R04

COD NAME
--- ------------
R01 Harry Potter
R04 Batman

SQL>


Thank you, sir. Your script works beautifully.
